# Sending a service call based on SOAP protocol

Tags: python, xml, soap, xsd, wsdl

This is the first time for me to use SOAP and I am trying to send a service call using **python**. I used **SOAPy** and **pysimplesoap** as client libraries.

I have the following:

1. [WSDL File](https://sandbox.payfort.com/payment/payat/merchants/payments.wsdl).
2. XSD File.
3. Method name that I'm trying to execute.
4. All the parameters needed.

What I want to do:

1. Execute the method.
2. Get the **xml file** returned from the method.

This is a working [PHP Script](http://pastie.org/private/oirp0mjvsdoc14g89zteqa) like what I want, but I need it in Python.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this piece of code:

```
from pysimplesoap.client import SoapClient
client = SoapClient(wsdl="your_file.wsdl",trace=False)
response = client.YourMehtod(p="parameter")
result = response['YourResult']
```

The things you need to get from this piece of code is:

1. "your_file.wsdl" should be a URL pointing to your WSDL's file location. Could be a HTTP URL, or a FILE stored on your file system.
2. `YourMethod` is the name of the method you are trying to call (to get all the methods available to you, use `print client` after the call in the second line of the code snippet.
3. `YourRestult` is the result you are getting from the call. Use `print response` to inspect all results you are getting.

You could also consider using `suds` library if SOAP CLIENT is all you care about.

Comment: 1. I got an **unexpected keyword argument** because of the _trace_ when initializing the SoapClient.
2. The 3rd line of the code throws a **TypeError** _call() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)_

Comment: For the **unexpected keyword**, you are probably using a different version of **pysimplesoap**. Just remove that parameter. The second error clearly is because your remote method takes more than one argument. Just add as many parameters as you need.

Comment: What type should the parameters be? I tried _dict_, array of _tuples_ and both failed.

Comment: I then switched to **suds** as you mentioned but when initializing the Client, I got _include schema at_ error when I added URL of the **wsdl** file and _unknown url type_ when I added the file location. **suds** does not support loading wsdl files that are stored locally?